# Need help solving a limit as x approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, economics

I have to take the limit of the first derivative of:
$$ U(x_i) = \bigg( \sum_i \alpha_i x_i^p \bigg)^\frac{1}{p} $$
as $x_i \rightarrow \infty$. 
The first derivative is 
$$ \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial x_i} = \frac{1}{p} \bigg( \sum_i \alpha_i x_i^p \bigg)^{\frac{1}{p} -1} \cdot p \alpha_i x_i^{p -1} =  \bigg( \sum_i \alpha_i x_i^p \bigg)^{\frac{1}{p} -1} \cdot  \alpha_i x_i^{p -1}   $$
I need help showing the following:
$$\lim_{x_i \rightarrow \infty} \bigg( \sum_i \alpha_i x_i^p \bigg)^{\frac{1 - p}{p}} \alpha_i x_i^{p - 1} = 0 $$
Where: 
$\sum_i \alpha_i = 1 $.
Currently, this is what I have:
$$\lim_{x_i \rightarrow \infty} \bigg( \sum_j \alpha_j x_j^p \bigg)^{\frac{1 - p}{p}} \alpha_i x_i^{p - 1} \\
= \lim_{x_i \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{\bigg( \sum_j \alpha_j x_j^p \bigg)^{\frac{1 - p}{p}}}{\alpha_i x_i^{1-p}}\\
= \lim_{x_i \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\bigg( \sum_j \alpha_j x_j^p \bigg)^{\frac{1 - p}{p}}}{\alpha_i \cdot \cdot \infty}\\
= \lim_{x_i \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\bigg( \sum_j \alpha_j x_j^p \bigg)^{\frac{1 - p}{p}}}{\infty} = 0 $$
As $\bigg( \sum_j \alpha_j x_j \bigg)^{\frac{1 - p}{p}$ is a constant. 
Thanks!

Comment: This is false if p=1

Comment: I'm by no means an expert, but I believe your expression to be ill-formed, as you use $i$ outside of the scope where it is defined (the sum).

Comment: Are you missing a summation sign? Or combining summation notation with Einsteinian notation?

Comment: OK, it seems that your summation index should be $j$ and that $i$ is a particular index for which it is true that $x_i\to\infty$. Is it the case that for all $j$, $x_j\to\infty$? Are you trying to show that $\lim_{x_i\rightarrow \infty} \bigg( \sum_j \alpha_j x_j^p \bigg)^{\frac{1 - p}{p}} \alpha_i x_i^{p - 1} = 0$?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, the limit is for an Inada condition, the expression above is actually the first derivative of my utility function (CES utility), the x_i is an entry in a vector so upon taking the derivative it appears outside of the summation expression by the chain rule.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I edited the question to make everything more clear.

Comment: Then you should take $\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial x_j}$, not with respect to $x_i$. You cannot re-use the index of the sum in this manner.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales ah I see, I think I have a solution now, thank you so much for your help!